# get around legacy app resolutoion requirement on 4k

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution

I am trying to run an old application (quickbooks timer) on a 4k monitor but the app requires 1080p or less.  Is there a way to make it look to that app that the resolution is 1080p?  
I have looked though the compatibility-administrator but the only resolution  related item changes the screen resolution for everything.   
PS.  My wife's retina macbook running windows has more than 1080p but the app runs fine there - no idea why.
On windows 8.1 64bit

Comment: What is the screen resolution on the macbook exactly?

Comment: the mac rez is 2560 x 1600

Comment: @zortacon: So the app terminates on a detecting a higher resolution than supported? Perhaps you can run it in a VM where you can define the resolution?